# How to use dynamic head in Next js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, meta-tags, vercel

before next js 13 we used to do dynamic head as an import. but in Next JS 13 they introduced the head.js class. this works when using a static page, but when loading a dynamic how can we change the title and desc in the head? i directly imported the next/head and then assign the data but it didn't change the head.

```
export default function DetailPage({ params: { itemid } }) {

const [datas, setDatas] = useState({});

  const getData = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "items", itemid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    setDatas(docSnap.data());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(datas).length == 0) {
      getData();
    }
  }, [datas]);

return (

<>
<Head>
        <title>{datas.title}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta
          name="keywords"
          content="some contents"
        />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={datas.desc}
        />
      </Head>

  <section>...</section>

</>

)

}
```

Comment: When you print `datas.title` did you get the real value ?

Comment: @dom1 yes it prompts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing you are using the `app` directory, the `Head` component has been replaced by the `generateMetadata` API. Usage could use something like this inside your page:

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";

export function MyPage(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  return <></>;
}

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  const data = await getMyData();
  return {
    // return your metadata here
  };
}
```

You can find a full API reference and a method for static metadata inside the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata).

Comment: thats not working either. i've tried statically and dynamically but nothing

Comment: I'm using firebase and i'm storing the fetched value inside useState. but the metadata only works in server side

Comment: it was my version, after upgrading it to the latest version it works

Comment: ... so now you have to make the same request twice if you wanted that data in your page? -1

Comment: In code yes. But fetch requests are automatically deduped and reused. Or using Reacts new `cache` funtion will also dedupe not fetch based calls. Also, pretty rude to downvote a valid answer based on the lack of one ones knowledge.

Comment: Poorly doucmented and not expressive enough. Next.js.

Comment: @MarekMaurizio I am not affiliated with Next.js, so sadly nothing I can do about that. But I actually am quite fond of the documentation.